# HTML5 Input Pattern to allow comma separator for thousands

Tags: regex, html, forms, input

Trying to put together a `regex` for an HTML5 input form, to allow the comma as a separator for thousands. So for example the following should all be valid:

- 20
- 3000
- 4,000
- 600000
- 7,000,000
- 8000000

My requirements are:

- only numbers allowed
- comma allowed
- any number greater than 0 but smaller than 99999999

I have this but it does not appear to be working:

```
[0-9,]{1,8}
```

*Please note, as far as I understood, HTML5 input patterns do not need `^` or `$` as these are assumed.*

Comment: Try [`(?!0+$)(?:\d{1,8}|\d{1,2}(?:,\d{3}){0,2})`](https://regex101.com/r/mG0cX8/1).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew this will not match with `800,000`

Comment: Then [`(?!0+$)(?!(?:\D*\d){9})(?:\d{1,8}|\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3}){0,2})`](https://regex101.com/r/eS6pU6/2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(?=.{1,10}$)\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})+|(?=.{1,8}$)\d+
```

Breaks down as:

```
(?=.{1,10}$)\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})+
```

- `(?=.{1,10}$)` lookahead to ensure that the total length is between 1 and 10 characters (to satisfy the `smaller than or equal to 99999999` requirement)
- `\d{1,3}` between one and 3 digits
- `(?:,\d{3})+` followed by at least one occurrence of: a comma followed by 3 digits

or

```
(?=.{1,8}$)\d+)
```

- `(?=.{1,8}$)` lookahead to ensure that the total length is between one and 8 characters (to satisfy the `smaller than or equal to 99999999` requirement)
- `\d+` at least one digit

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/lP4dZ5/3)